# mouseover or mouseenter or onhover event for Kendo Grid custom button?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-angular2

[image: My Kendo Grid]

The following image shows a small button with a custom edit button on each row of Kendo Grid, I implemented the button using the below code.

```
command: [{
 name: "MyEdit",
 click: myFunction,
 template: "<a id= 'myEdit' class='k-grid-MyEdit k-button'><span class='k-icon k-i-edit'></span></a>"
         }]


function myFunction(e) {
       var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
}
```

The custom button click event works fine but my requirement is - "onmouseover" , "mouseenter" or "onhover" event for this button.
I tried googling and found no other events apart from click event.
I need inbuilt command button event only, like "click" is this example.

please suggest me a solution or correct me if something's wrong in my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo doesn't provides any other event type but `click`. You need to bind it yourself. That is easy, just bind the events to the grid's element filtering by the button class:

```
$(grid.element).on("mouseover mouseenter", ".k-grid-MyEdit", function(e) {
    console.log("Button event type: ", e.type);
    $(this).click();
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IcEvIpiv).